# "JAXWS wsimport" says XPath is null in a "jaxb file binding"

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, wsdl, wsimport

I am trying to generate stub files using jaxws wsimport.
In the WSDL there are two types which are conflicting:
line 68: `<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DAGSBROTTFELLT" type="s:string" />`

and line 119: `<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DAGS_BROTTFELLT" type="s:string" />`

The reason is that wsimport does not preserves the underscore character "_" and thinks that the both names are the same.

I have created a jaxb bindings file to name explicitly the resulting Java class.

But the wsimport says:

```
[ERROR] XPath error: null
line 11 of file:/C:/Users/deyan/ss_workspace/MVS%20Services/src/is/mvs/services/ws/xjb/companyInfo.xjb
```

I have tested the xpath string in 
http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output
And it truly returns the element.

Please help to figure out why the wsimport says that the xpath is null.

Thank you in advance!

This is my WSDL:
https://gognxml.uh.is/xml_service.asmx?WSDL

This is the jaxb bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxws:bindings
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  wsdlLocation="https://gognxml.uh.is/xml_service.asmx?WSDL">

  <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
  <enableAsyncMapping>false</enableAsyncMapping>
  <jaxws:bindings          node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/s:schema/s:complexType[@name='Faersla']/s:sequence/s:element[@name='DAGS_BROTTFELLT']">
    <jaxb:class name="Dags_Brottfellt"/>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that the XPath expression uses the `s` namespace prefix (e.g. `s:schema`), but I don't see that namespace prefix declared anywhere. Is it supposed to be declared on one of the `<jaxws:bindings>` elements? Or where are such prefixes expected to be declared? Usually, having them declared in the input XML is not sufficient. But I don't know anything about wsimport.

Comment: @LarsH I have made this change in the jaxb file inspired by your comment and it worked:
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

I have renamed the xmlns:xs to xmlns:s

Thank you! 
If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You should prefer the standard prefixes `xs` or `xsd` for that namespace, instead of using `s`, which will likely confuse people. Note that the prefix in your xpath doesn't need to match the prefix in the wsdl, they just have to be bound to the same namespace URN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I notice is that the XPath expression uses the `s` namespace prefix (e.g. `s:schema`), but I don't see that namespace prefix declared anywhere. Is it supposed to be declared on one of the `<jaxws:bindings>` elements? Or where are such prefixes expected to be declared? Usually, having them declared in the input XML is not sufficient. But I don't know anything about wsimport.

P.S. Looks like the `xs` prefix is not used, so maybe it was supposed to be `s`. As you already confirmed in your comment. :-)

Comment: This alludes to the correct answer, but doesn't actually say it: you also have to define all the namespaces for use in the xpath in the root element too.